# Receiving error while iterating over a map in javascript in LWC - "e.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, map, lwc-wire-adapter

I am getting a different error and can not seem to figure it out now for a coupe of hours,

Here's my code :

```
createMapMarkers(boatData) {
 console.log('DATA :'+boatData);
 const newMarkers = boatData.map((boat) => {
 return {
 title : boat.Name,
 location : {
 Latitude : boat.Geolocation__Latitude__s,
 Longitude : boat.Geolocation__Longitude__s
                }
            }
        });
 newMarkers.unshift({
 title : LABEL_YOU_ARE_HERE,
 icon : ICON_STANDARD_USER,
 location : {
 Latitude : this.latitude,
 Longitude : this.longitude
            }
        });
 
 this.mapMarkers = newMarkers;
 this.isLoading = false;
    }
```

I am getting this error :

```
modules/c/boatsNearMe.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's u/wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[e.map is not a function]
    at h.createMapMarkers (modules/c/boatsNearMe.js:4)
    at h.wiredBoatsJSON (modules/c/boatsNearMe.js:4)
    at b.dispatchEvent (aura_prod.js:6)
    at yi (/components/force/lds.js:2)
    at eval (/components/force/lds.js:2)
    at eval (/components/force/lds.js:2)
```

I checked the piece of code by running on [Here on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and it worked perfectly. It is only throwing error in LWC.

Comment: how is `createMapMarkers` being invoked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above code has correct syntax provided `boatData` is an array. It looks like the Javascript object you have `boatData` is not an Array and hence you get an exception that `.map` is not a function.

You can easily reproduce this with below Javascript code

```
let object_x = {};
object_x.map( x => {
   return x;
});
```

This will result in an error ***Error: object_x.map is not a function***

Looks like the boatData is a JSON string and you can use `JSON.parse(boatData)` to cast to the Javascript array.

Comment: that's it, I was about to remove the question or post the answer. I over looked that Apex was returning JSON.serialize object. use JSON.parse and worked fine. Thank you.